# How to upload image file to spring mvc resource folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

im working on a spring mvc project . i want to upload image and save it to resources/img/folder.

I tried below code but it does not save the image to the directory.

```
@Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    try {
            // MultipartFile file = uploadItem.getFileData();
            String fileName = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            if (multipartFile.getSize() > 0) {
                inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();

                System.out.println("File Size:::" + multipartFile.getSize());

                fileName = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/") + "/students/"
                        + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                System.out.println("OriginalFilename:" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
                System.out.println("fileName----"+fileName);
                int readBytes = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Exception**

```
11:00:39,436 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) File Size:::7346
11:00:39,436 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) java.io.FileNotFoundException
: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment65ea7dd580659db3\ObviousR
esponseWeb-1.2-SNAPSHOT.war-3a7509e73dad1cba\resources\students\zzzz.jpg (The sy
stem cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: what error / exception you see in logs ?

Comment: no errors a re showing on server console.

Comment: okies.. could you add more debug statements after each LOC and share them ?

Comment: i have these code but still no exception
try {
      multipartFile.transferTo(resourceLoader.getResource("resources/css/"+multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()).getFile());
     } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

Comment: What I mean is put debug log at method entry, then before and after `if` (*with evaluated value*) and so forth. This will help us with more information to zero down exact issue

Comment: 11:00:39,436 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) File Size:::7346
11:00:39,436 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) java.io.FileNotFoundException
: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment65ea7dd580659db3\ObviousR
esponseWeb-1.2-SNAPSHOT.war-3a7509e73dad1cba\resources\students\zzzz.jpg (The sy
stem cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 2):

```
   String saveDirectory=request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"images\\";//to save to images folder
   String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();//getting file name
   System.out.println("directory with file name: " + saveDirectory+fileName);
   multipartFile.transferTo(new File(saveDirectory + fileName));
```

Comment: this code will upload the image to webapp/resources/images directory. I didn't know `spring`. By guessing only here I'm giving this code.

Comment: so check the path with sys.out ststmnt.